# How to pass parameters from appDelegate to ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to pass some parameters from the appDelegate to a viewController before loading it.

This is the code i'm trying to use (in the appDelegate.swift):

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let secondView = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tab") as UITabBarController
secondView.variable = "xxxx"
self.window?.rootViewController = secondView;
```

but the compiler shows the following error:

> UITabBarController does not have a member named 'variable'

Even thought, in the TabBarController class (TabBarController.swift) i have the following:

```
import UIKit
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {
var variable:String!
...etc
```

What's the error?
Please give a clear explanation as i'm a beginner in Swift.
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `TabBarController`, but you instantiate `as UITabBarController`.

Answer (score 1):

Your second line should be

```
let secondView = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tab") as TabBarController
```